# Celery and Celery beat wit django after running in docker container running some job

Tags: django, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I am trying to run django celery and celery beat.
After I start celery and celery beat
this process is running every second. Is this normal?

```
celery-1       | [2024-03-10 16:08:11,479: INFO/MainProcess] Running job "EventPublisher.send_events (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2024-03-10 16:08:12 IST)" (scheduled at 2024-03-10 16:08:11.478374+05:30)
celery-1       | [2024-03-10 16:08:11,479: INFO/MainProcess] Job "EventPublisher.send_events (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2024-03-10 16:08:12 IST)" executed successfully
celery-beat-1  | [2024-03-10 16:08:11,767: INFO/MainProcess] Running job "EventPublisher.send_events (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2024-03-10 16:08:12 IST)" (scheduled at 2024-03-10 16:08:11.766830+05:30)
celery-beat-1  | [2024-03-10 16:08:11,767: INFO/MainProcess] Job "EventPublisher.send_events (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2024-03-10 16:08:12 IST)" executed successfully
```

I tried clearing redis db
also tried uninstalling and installing redis,celery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it !! Thank you for your help !!
The thing was I was using some PHONEPAY SDK for accepting payments. which was using aps-scheduler in background which was triggering this event.
I dont know how it showed up in celery logs.
i solved it by

```
PhonePePaymentClient(should_publish_events=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `django_celery_beat_periodictask` DB table, it may contain some records of tasks which can cause such behavior.

Comment: @krisin
Solved it !! Thank you for your help !!
the thing was I was using some PHONEPAY SDK for accepting payments.
which was using aps-scheduler in background which was triggering this event.